# Tensorflow inference becomes slower and slower due to eval() function

Tags: tensorflow, inference

So I have a frozen tensorflow model, which I can use to classify images. When I try to use this model to inference image one bye one, the model just runs slower and slower. I searched and find the problem may cause by eval() function, which will keep add new nodes to the graph, thus slows down the procedure.

Below is the key parts of my code:

```
with open('/tmp/frozen_resnet_v1_50.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    sess1 = tf.Session()
    sess = tf.Session()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
        for f in files:
            # Read image one by one and preprocess
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, f))
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # BGR 2 RGB

            img = image_preprocessing_fn(img, _IMAGE_HEIGHT, _IMAGE_WIDTH)  # This function contains tf functions
            img = img.eval(session=sess1)

            img = np.reshape(img, [-1, _IMAGE_HEIGHT, _IMAGE_WIDTH, _IMAGE_CHANNEL])    # the input shape is 4 dimension

            # Feed image to model
            data = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
            predict = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('resnet_v1_50/predictions/Softmax:0')

            out = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={data: img})
            indices = np.argmax(out, 1)

            print('Current image name: %s, predict result: %s' % (f, indices))

    sess1.close()
    sess.close()
```

PS:I use "sess1" to do the preprocess, I think maybe this is  inappropriate. Hope someone can show me the correct way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answers...Here is my solution, it works!

```
with open('/tmp/frozen_resnet_v1_50.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=[None, None, 3])
    y = image_preprocessing_fn(x, _IMAGE_HEIGHT, _IMAGE_WIDTH)

    sess = tf.Session()
    data = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    predict = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('resnet_v1_50/predictions/Softmax:0')

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
        for f in files:
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, f))
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # BGR 2 RGB
            img = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: img})

            img = np.reshape(img, [-1, _IMAGE_HEIGHT, _IMAGE_WIDTH, _IMAGE_CHANNEL])

            out = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={data: img})
            indices = np.argmax(out, 1)

            print('Current image name: %s, predict result: %s' % (f, out))

    sess.close()
```